# Pandas Interpolation with Groupby Date to Fill Missing Values

Tags: pandas

I would like someone to explain to me the workings of the interpolation method alongside groupby. The problem is functionally solved, however, it is rather slow, and I still do not understand the behavior of the methods.

A snapshot of the data:

```
print(df)
   archiveDatefut     vol
0       6/16/2014  1.4950
1       6/16/2014  1.1775
2       6/16/2014  1.0275
3       6/16/2014     NaN
4       6/16/2014     NaN
5       6/16/2014     NaN
6       6/16/2014  1.0125
7       6/16/2014  0.7050
8       6/16/2014  0.5550
9       6/16/2014  0.4938
10      6/16/2014     NaN
11      6/16/2014     NaN
12      6/16/2014  0.4700
13      6/16/2014  0.3919
14      6/16/2014  0.3694
15      6/16/2014  0.3488
16      6/16/2014     NaN
17      6/16/2014     NaN
18      6/16/2014     NaN
19      6/17/2014  1.4950
20      6/17/2014  1.1800
21      6/17/2014  1.0300
22      6/17/2014     NaN
23      6/17/2014     NaN
24      6/17/2014     NaN
25      6/17/2014  1.0138
26      6/17/2014  0.7050
27      6/17/2014  0.5550
28      6/17/2014  0.4938
29      6/17/2014     NaN
```

So I have the data above and I want to groupby the archiveDateFut , fill in the missing vol column values with interpolated values by day. I have tried the following methods.

```
#set index
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.archiveDatefut)

#method 1 (I don't expect or want this version)

df['vol1'] = df['vol'].groupby(df.index.date).apply(lambda x: x).interpolate(method='linear').reset_index()['vol'].values



#method 2 (this is what I want)

vols = [] 

for _,day in df.groupby(df.index.date):
    volday = day.vol.interpolate(method='linear')
    vols.append(volday)
    

df['vol2'] = pd.concat(vols).values

print(df)
```

```
               archiveDatefut     vol      vol1      vol2
archiveDatefut                                           
2014-06-16          6/16/2014  1.4950  1.495000  1.495000
2014-06-16          6/16/2014  1.1775  1.177500  1.177500
2014-06-16          6/16/2014  1.0275  1.027500  1.027500
2014-06-16          6/16/2014     NaN  1.023750  1.023750
2014-06-16          6/16/2014     NaN  1.020000  1.020000
2014-06-16          6/16/2014     NaN  1.016250  1.016250
2014-06-16          6/16/2014  1.0125  1.012500  1.012500
2014-06-16          6/16/2014  0.7050  0.705000  0.705000
2014-06-16          6/16/2014  0.5550  0.555000  0.555000
2014-06-16          6/16/2014  0.4938  0.493800  0.493800
2014-06-16          6/16/2014     NaN  0.485867  0.485867
2014-06-16          6/16/2014     NaN  0.477933  0.477933
2014-06-16          6/16/2014  0.4700  0.470000  0.470000
2014-06-16          6/16/2014  0.3919  0.391900  0.391900
2014-06-16          6/16/2014  0.3694  0.369400  0.369400
2014-06-16          6/16/2014  0.3488  0.348800  0.348800
2014-06-16          6/16/2014     NaN  0.635350  0.348800
2014-06-16          6/16/2014     NaN  0.921900  0.348800
2014-06-16          6/16/2014     NaN  1.208450  0.348800
2014-06-17          6/17/2014  1.4950  1.495000  1.495000
2014-06-17          6/17/2014  1.1800  1.180000  1.180000
2014-06-17          6/17/2014  1.0300  1.030000  1.030000
2014-06-17          6/17/2014     NaN  1.025950  1.025950
2014-06-17          6/17/2014     NaN  1.021900  1.021900
2014-06-17          6/17/2014     NaN  1.017850  1.017850
2014-06-17          6/17/2014  1.0138  1.013800  1.013800
2014-06-17          6/17/2014  0.7050  0.705000  0.705000
2014-06-17          6/17/2014  0.5550  0.555000  0.555000
2014-06-17          6/17/2014  0.4938  0.493800  0.493800
2014-06-17          6/17/2014     NaN  0.493800  0.493800
```

So on first glance everything looks the same, however, there is a big difference in what I expect if there are no values between interpolation values. Note the following:

```
2014-06-16          6/16/2014     NaN  0.635350  0.348800
2014-06-16          6/16/2014     NaN  0.921900  0.348800
2014-06-16          6/16/2014     NaN  1.208450  0.348800
```

I can't seem to figure out what the difference between the two methods is and why it is happening. The difference from expectations happens consistently when there are no values at the end, so where a new day begins the values prior to that will have this unexpected behavior.

Method 2 gives me exactly what I want, however, it is prohibitively slow.

Answer (score 0):

you can try using the `transform` function instead of the for loop

```
df['vol2'] = df.groupby(df.index.date)['vol'].transform(lambda x: x.interpolate())
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that works. I was wondering if you have any insights in to what is going on with my current version and why it gives me those values, it is really bugging me , pun intended!